# what cpu instructions (for any architecture) do not do math

Tags: emulation, cpu

what cpu instructions (for any architecture) do not do math?

as it seems illogical that a cpu could could operate on pure math (eg carry, vectors, multiplication, addition, subtraction, division, and any other types of math)

eg, in psudocode

```
mov 1, r2
```

would do

```
r2 = 1
```

like at least 80% to 90% of a cpu's instruction would be for math, what would the other 20% to 10% of instructions operate on and how would those be accomplished

for example, take the ARM instruction WFE, its operation in psuedo code (according to ARM v7-A/R manual) is

```
if ConditionPassed() then
    EncodingSpecificOperations();
    if EventRegistered() then
        ClearEventRegister();
    else
        if HaveVirtExt() && !IsSecure() && !CurrentModeIsHyp() && HCR.TWE == ‘1’ then
            HSRString = Zeros(25);
            HSRString<0> = ‘1’;
            WriteHSR(‘000001’, HSRString);
            TakeHypTrapException();
        else
            WaitForEvent();
```

TakeHypTrapException(); and WaitForEvent(); i do not think could be implemented with math alone, however i may be wrong

Comment: See the work of Godel, the theory of recursive functions and logic in general. Every proposition/predicate can be mapped to a number and working with number is probably what you call "math" here (arithmetic being a more correct term). Now RF (and the T formal system) are expressive as Turing machines and TM are probably what you more easily associate with a general algorithm (like the WFE one). So basically everything is math, computers are just encoding everything as numbers, the value of the signals of a datapath in a CPU form a number. Computing is just moving numbers around.

Comment: However this is a very low level and technical view. It's hard to think of an image as very big number (though it is) rather than a structured sequence of numerical fields. So the CPU instructions are usually classified as arithmetic, logic, branches, tests, IO, control and so on.

Comment: @MargaretBloom so even file IO and device communication can be done with arithmetic or numbers and addresses only?

Comment: Yes, but that's the theory. The "Zen view" of the thing. If you thing about it, IO is just moving a number from the CPU to the device. In practice it's easier, better and more productive to have arithmetic and non-arithmetic instructions.

Comment: @MargaretBloom ok, would the non arithmetic functions be implemented using arithmetic? and how would the moving from a cpu to a device work? as, per unix, a program cannot access anything beyond its designated address space allocation, wich is usually a few MB or GB, depending on the implementation and the bit size of the program, it would be impossible to access memory in wich exceeds its own allocated space size

Comment: You may be interested in a Computer Architecture book, for the practical part. The theory can be found in a Theory of Computation/Type theory/Logic book. The bridge between the two being the concept of Encoding/Code. I'm more versed on Linux than Unix but even Unix had the file description abstraction to talk to devices, so I don't see how address spaces (especially the MiB/GiB figures) come into play. Unless you were talking about MMIO but in that case you may want to look at the privilege separation between the kernel and the user programs.

Comment: for example, Memory Management Unit's, normally a program is assigned an address range in 32 bit from 0x0 to 0xFFFFFFFF, and in 64 bit, 0x0 to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (if that is correct) and cannot access anything beyond 0xFFFFFFFF for 32 and 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF for 64, if a 32 bit program wants to access the memory of a 64 bit program at say 0xF0FFFFFFFFFF0000 to 0xFAFFFFFFFFFF0000 how would it do so

Comment: Paging is an extensive topic, see for example x86 PAE. A 32-bit program may indeed share memory with a 64-bit memory easily with the usual IPC sharing methods (e.g. `mmap`). A 32-bit program/device without paging is indeed unable to access memory above 4 GiB. That's why there's a PCI hole at the top of the 4 GiB.

Comment: ill have a look when i have time